# How do I compile this github project on my pc?

Tags: cygwin

I am new to GitHub sites
I do not understand the compile of this.

This project https://github.com/dougmencken/HeadOverHeels/releases/tag/v1.31pre has been uploaded on gitHub.

How can I compile the source code of this project and transform it into a .exe application where I run it on my PC with windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried running ./cygwin-build.sh in a cygwin bash shell?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually run this. I started to, but it got too involved. I don't have X in my Cygwin installation, and I didn't really want to install Allego anyway.

But here's what I've been able to gather from the various README's.

Tools you will need: `wget`, `gcc-core`, `gcc-g++`, `make`, `tar`, `cmake`, `xorg-server`, `xorg-server-common`, `xorg-server-devel`. Possibly others (`m4`? `autoconf`?).

You'll also need to download and install Allegro, it appears.

```
$ mkdir HeadOverHeels
$ cd HeadOverHeels
$ wget https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/releases/download/5.2.5.0/allegro-5.2.5.0.tar.gz
$ tar xf allegro-5.2.5.0.tar.gz
$ cd allegro-5.2.5.0.tar.gz
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..

# if all goes successfully

$ make
$ make install
$ wget https://github.com/dougmencken/HeadOverHeels/archive/v1.31pre.tar.gz
$ tar xf v1.31pre.tar.gz
$ cd HeadOverHeels-1.31pre
$ ./cygwin-build.sh
```